# In R getting an error "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

Tags: r, error-handling, syntax

I have 332 csv files in "specdata" directory and when I am trying to get mean of pollutants of selected files, getting this error: **error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection**

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\1911120\\Desktop\\GIT")

pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant,id=1:332){
  for (file in id){
    path <- paste(getwd(),"/directory","/",sprintf("%03d",file),".csv",sep="")
    data <- read.csv(path)
    pollutant_data <- data[pollutant]
    mean_data <- c(mean_data,pollutant_data[!is.na(pollutant_data)])
  }
  mean(mean_data)
}

pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

Comment: If you search on stackoverflow with `[r] pollutantmean` you'll get lot of helpful posts.

Comment: This error sounds like it is being caused by `read.csv`. Most likely, there is something wrong with the file path.

Comment: Maybe `paste(getwd(),"/", directory, "/",sprintf("%03d",file),".csv",sep="")`?